# rule-based element selection from a matrix

Tags: matrix

For simplicity, I give a (3,3) matrix below, though my matrix is of a larger dimension. My objective is, after some matrix manipulations, to select Maximum element(s) in a row and a column, and place zero all the cells except the maximum elements.

```
mat = {{1, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {4, 1, 2}};
one = {1, 1, 1};
colTot = one.mat;
rowTot = mat.one;

colStd = Table[matColStd[i, j] = mat[[i, j]]/colTot[[j]], 
{i,3}, {j,3}]//N
rowStd = Table[matRowStd[i, j] = mat[[j, i]]/rowTot[[j]],
{j,3}, {i,3}] // N
```

> solColMat = {{0,0.5714,0.4545}, {0,0, 0}, {0.6666,0,0}};
>
> solRowMat ={{0,0,0.5}, {0,0,0.5714},{0.5714,0,0}};

The above `Code` column-wise standardizes `mat`, denoted by `colStd`. Using the same matrix `mat` I also introduce a row-standardization `rowStd`. The standardization of the `Code` works just fine.

My purpose is to create two new matrices `solColMat` and `solRowMat`, which respectively select `maximum` element(s) from each column and from each row. Non-maximum elements are converted to zeros. The final matrices, `solColMat` and `solRowMat`, are given above for clarification purposes.

I would like to have your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rowStd = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ mat
```

> {{1/10, 2/5, 1/2}, {1/7, 2/7, 4/7}, {4/7, 1/7, 2/7}}

```
colStd = Transpose[Normalize[#, Total] & /@ Transpose[mat]]
```

> {{1/6, 4/7, 5/11}, {1/6, 2/7, 4/11}, {2/3, 1/7, 2/11}}

```
maxSelect = Map[Clip[#, {Max @ #, ∞}, {0, 0}] &];

solRowMat  = maxSelect @ rowStd
```

> {{0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 4/7}, {4/7, 0, 0}}

```
solColMat = Transpose @ maxSelect @ Transpose @ colStd
```

> {{0, 4/7, 5/11}, {0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 0, 0}}

Alternative ways to select the maximum from each row:

```
maxSelect2 =  Map[#  UnitStep[# - Max @ #]&];

maxSelect3 = Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", 1}]&];
```

The last one is more flexible in that you can change `1` to `k` to take the largest `k` elements in each row and set the rest to `0`.

Comment: In the case of a matrix, say (100,100), I may have to choose not the maximum only but the largest two or three elements in each matrix. Would it be feasible in your `Code` to do so?

Comment: Sorry that my explanation was missing an important piece of information, which is to exclude the numbers in the diagonal elements of `mat`. The selection should only consider the off-diagonal elements in `mat`.

Comment: @Tugrul, for largest `k` elements you can try `maxSelect3` replacing `1` with `k`.

Comment: You can multiply `rowStd ` with `1- IdentityMatrix[3]`  or subtract from `rowStat` `-Max[mat] IdentityMatrix[3]` before using `maxSelect` (Similarly for `colStd`.)

Comment: @kglr the `Threshold` thing is pretty handy, never used it before. So many functions are there to get used to :) By the way +1.

Comment: @PlatoManiac, thank you for the vote.  `Clip` with an appropriate threshold in the second argument is probably faster, but `Threshold` is really convenient.

Comment: @kglr: Your answer gave me what I aimed to obtain plus `Normalize` is also what I learned from you. Thank you very much for the solution to my problem.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, my pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

I will do something like this. `Unitize` is pretty useful here.

```
With[{max = Max@#}, max Unitize[#, max]] & /@ rowStd
```

> {{0., 0., 0.5}, {0., 0., 0.571429}, {0.571429, 0., 0.}}

For the colums first `Transpose` to get to rows and then transpose back.

```
With[{max = Max@#}, max Unitize[#, max]] & /@ (Transpose@colStd) // Transpose
```

> {{0., 0.571429, 0.454545}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.666667, 0., 0.}}

#### Note

This works when the maximum entry (in each row or column) is positive. However the methods given by @kglr explore more general options and `UnitStep` will probably give speed benefits for large matrices.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your comments. Thank you for your help.